# Does Entity Framework 6 Have Ability to Add Included Columns When Adding an Index Out of the Box?

Tags: entity-framework

I have implemented as suggested here to handle included columns on indexes using EF v3.1.5: https://mindbyte.nl/2017/12/26/Create-indexes-with-included-columns-with-Entity-Framework-Core-using-code-first.html

And you get this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Blah] ON [Blah]
(
    [ColumnName] ASC
)
INCLUDE([IncludedColumnName1],[IncludedColumnName2]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

INCLUDE([IncludedColumnName1],[IncludedColumnName2]) - is what you get with the annotation extension.

Does EF v6 have this out of the box? I do not seem to be able to locate any info on this.

Answer (score -1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations#included-columns

From the site:

Some relational databases allow you to configure a set of columns which get included in the index, but aren't part of its "key". This can significantly improve query performance when all columns in the query are included in the index either as key or nonkey columns, as the table itself doesn't need to be accessed. For more information on SQL Server included columns, see the documentation.

In the following example, the Url column is part of the index key, so any query filtering on that column can use the index. But in addition, queries accessing only the Title and PublishedOn columns will not need to access the table and will run more efficiently:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
        .HasIndex(p => p.Url)
        .IncludeProperties(
            p => new { p.Title, p.PublishedOn });
}
```

Comment: I will give this a try and seems like a potentially legit answer. Thanks